# Python SciPy Optimize -- Minimize function not iterating, x-values not changing at all

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm new to `SciPy` and the optimize function, so this may be a simple question. I followed the tutorials and set up the basic optimize function. I outlined the objective function, bounds, constraints, initial guess, etc. When I go run the function, no optimization happens. It says 'Optimization terminated successfully' but the x-values that get produced are the same as the ones I put in as the initial guess. I'll put my code below:

```py
def objective_fcn(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]
    profit = (128375.0 + x3*147187.0)*149.12*(1+x1) - (44.92*(1+x2))*(x3*147187.0 + 20326.0 + 147187.0*(1-x3))
    return profit * -1

def ineq_const(x):
    x3 = x[2]
    return (1-x3)*147187.0 - 128375.0

x0 = [0.1,0.0,0.1]

bounds_x1 = (-1.0, 0.75)
bounds_x2 = (-1.0, 1.0)
bounds_x3 = (-1.0, 1.0)
bounds = [bounds_x1, bounds_x2, bounds_x3]

const1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': ineq_const}
consts = [const1]

result = minimize(objective_fcn, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=consts)

print("The full result is: ")
print(result)
```

I've attached the results as well, note how it's the same as the `[0.1, 0.0, 0.1]` I entered as my initial guess.

**Results from optimization:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replayed your example locally and it is looking like you are facing an exploding gradient issue: the algorithm tries to update the parameter but the step sizes are too large and it moves it out of the space allowed by the constraint. Since this is forbidden, no update is happening. To reduce the step size, scaling the objective function is enough:

```py
def objective_fcn(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]
    profit = (128375.0 + x3*147187.0)*149.12*(1+x1) - (44.92*(1+x2))*(x3*147187.0 + 20326.0 + 147187.0*(1-x3))
    return profit * -1 * 1e-7
```

which converges to:

```
The full result is:
     fun: -3.84099195200049
     jac: array([-2.19485256,  0.75246841, -3.84099194])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 12
     nit: 3
    njev: 3
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.75     , -1.       ,  0.1278102])
```

Multiply the objective value by `-1e7` to know the optimal profit.

I picked `1e-7` at second trial (`1e-5` failed first). It can be interpreted as a manual tuning of the learning rate, and if you want to automate that, look into hyperparameter optimization in ML - for instance.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. Only question I have left is, do I need to modify anything in my inequality constraint when I multiply the profit by 1e-7? Or can I leave it exactly as is and it still works properly?